# Is it possible to de-cap a ceramic capacitor

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

Would it be possible to remove the case from a ceramic capacitor ? Like the ones surrounding the IC in this picture?

[image]

Comment: This image is very misleading to anyone who needs a picture to see what a ceramic capacitor is. You say "the _one_ shown in the picture". That's obviously the large black thing, which is _not_ a capacitor.

Comment: By "de-cap", do you mean "de-solder?" There are literally thousands of google articles, links, and videos about desoldering surface-mount components. Victor, you need to be more pro-active about researching your own answers first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question isn't about design or even about _how_things work.

Comment: The question was closed as "unclear".  I modified it to clean it up.  I think we should reopen it, especially since there are currently 18 upvotes on its answers, and a good pun besides :)

Answer (score 10):

These capacitors do not have an outer case, so there is nothing to remove.

They consist of fine conducting membranes between layers of ceramic; the same ceramic body also forms the outer shell. The electrodes at the ends connect the plates to each other and the outside world.

If you want to see how they work, I'd suggest splitting them in half along the long axis and using a microscope.

Comment: You can also solder a wire on one end and pull. A bit crude but usually breaks off the pad (ah the joys of trying to solder on testing wires and pulling too hard). Not much to see though as you say.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Which would significantly reduce the capacity to whatever the footprint does, and as such literally de-cap(acitor) the capacitor. I consider that a successful secondary answer ;-)

Answer (score 8):

What Simon [said](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/235079/7036).

I would only like to add pictures.

[image]  ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_types#Ceramic_capacitors))

[image: Cross-section of an MLCC capacitor. Micro-photograph.] ([source](http://www.gideonlabs.com/posts/failed-1210-mlccs/))

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no "cap" in a monolithic surface-mount ceramic capacitor like those. That is what "monolithic" means: "one-piece".  If you had mentioned WHY you think you want to do this, more helpful responses may be possible.